# Visible watermark (ex libris) on Mobi files

Tags: watermark, epub

We have a client selling ebooks and he wants to add the buyer's name on every page of the book (for example in the footer) so that it discourages him to share it too widely. Apparently this is called adding an "ex libris". Our client wants to sell ebooks in PDF/ePub/Mobi formats.

I've searched the Interweb about how to do this and so far I've found that doing this to PDFs is quite easy, that there is [a library](https://github.com/pettarin/exlibris) to do exactly this on ePubs. But I've found close to nothing related to mobi files.

So my questions are :

- Is it possible to add text on every page of a given .mobi file, for example in the footer?
- If it's not possible, how accurate would it be to convert a watermarked epub to the mobi format? What would be the best tools and practices for the job?

This discussion is **not** about how I could add a hidden watermark to the files through some form of steganography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done something similar before to use a footer image at the bottom of each page in a Mobi file. This image could contain the name of the buyer.

```
<style>
    body{
        background-image:url('[watermarkpath].PNG');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-position:center bottom; 
        background-size:contain; 
    } 
</style>
```

I suggest making the image itself transparent so that it doesn't interfere with the text. Hope this helps!

Comment: How would you then include the css on every page of the mobi file ?

Comment: You can just add this into your main Stylesheet (assuming you have one that is in every chapter of the book) and it should show up on every page! If not: just add it to the head of each chapter...

Comment: I meant what tools are you using to edit the mobi file ? The files I get are coming directly from the client and already compiled. I do not generate them myself in any way. What I'd like to do is to automate the process of just adding an ex-libris to them before shipping to the buyers. How would I do that ?

Comment: You need to get an ePub from them, unzip it and then edit the main CSS file... You will have to be able to actually edit the files in order to make any solution work.

Comment: So you're actually editing an ePub file and then converting it to Mobi, right ? In this case there was a secondary question : How accurate is the conversion from ePub to Mobi for a complex ePub ? Do you have any advices on how to get the best results ?

Comment: Exactly. You can even upload an ePub directly to KDP for Amazon... Using the Kindlgen tool ePub to Mobi conversion is pretty much lossless... The file size grows and obviously some compatibility things change across devices but the main issue is how eBook files behave on Amazon devices vs others, not how well ePub converts to Mobi.